# If statement which automatically populates another column based on a value (Outlook : VBA)

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to create an `If`/`Then` statement but I am not sure how to do this.

Below is the code which sets UDF2 as the value <> str2 and then when a value is selected from this list; this is saved in UDF2.

```
If str2 <> "" Then
    Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(2))
    If (objProperty Is Nothing) Then
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(udf(2), olKeywords)
    End If
    objProperty.Value = str2
    msg.Save
End If
```

What i would like this to do is store the selected value in UDF2- If the selected value = "A" then UDF2 is populated with value "A" and this also automatically populates UDF3 with value "B"

Below is what i have tried; I am not sure which order the code should be in or if this is even the correct way for the If and Then condition?

```
' save information in UDF2
If str2 <> "" Then
    Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(2))
Else
    If str2 = "A" Then 
    'set UDF3 as the value B
    Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(list(3), olKeywords) 

    If (objProperty Is Nothing) Then
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(udf(2), olKeywords)
    End If

    objProperty.Value = str2
    objProperty.Value = str3
    msg.Save
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this really VBA?? I can't say I follow all the logic here, but the following deals with most of it. Also, I'm not sure why you overwrite ObjProperty.Value twice prior to the msg,save

```
If str2 <> "" Then  
    If str2 = "A" Then 
        'set UDF3 as the value B
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(list(3), olKeywords) 
        else
        Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties(udf(2))
    end if
end if
If (objProperty Is Nothing) Then
    Set objProperty = msg.UserProperties.Add(udf(2), olKeywords)
End If
```